# Confused as to use a class or a function: Writing XML files using lxml and Python

Tags: python, lxml

I need to write XML files using lxml and Python.

However, I can't figure out whether to use a `class` to do this or a function. The point being, this is the first time I am developing a proper software and deciding where and why to use a `class` still seems mysterious.

I will illustrate my point.

For example, consider the following function based code I wrote for adding a subelement to a etree root.

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element('document')

def createSubElement(text, tagText = ""):
    etree.SubElement(root, text)
    # How do I do this: element.text = tagText

createSubElement('firstChild')
createSubElement('SecondChild')
```

As expected, the output of this is:

```
<document>
  <firstChild/>
  <SecondChild/>
</document>
```

However as you can notice the comment, I have no idea how to do set the text variable using this approach.

Is using a `class` the only way to solve this? And if yes, can you give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works:

```
def createSubElement(text, tagText = ""):
    elem = etree.SubElement(root, text)
    elem.text = tagText

createSubElement('firstChild', 'first one')
createSubElement('SecondChild', 'second one')

print etree.tostring(root)
```

Using a class rather than a function has mostly to do with *keeping state* in the class's instances (in very few use cases will a class make sense if there's no state-keeping required), which has nothing to do with your problem -- as the code shows, your problem was simply that you were not binding any name to the element returned from the `SubElement` call, and therefore of course you were unable to further manipulate that element (e.g. by setting its `text` attribute) in the rest of your function.

Comment: Oh wow, I wonder how I overlooked such a thing. Thank you. Do you think this approach is good or do I need to do this using a class?

Comment: @PulpFiction, if you want to keep per-instance state (for example because you may be handling more than one xml tree during the run), or in a few other pretty marginal cases even without per-instance state (if you want to use operator overloading, inheritance, and the like) then classes are a must.  Otherwise, the normal Python style prefers functions -- a class that has no per-instance state (or at least falls in one of the other special cases above listed) is just boilerplate and overhead, so why bother?

Comment: I get it now. Thanks! I will be handling one tree per run but just adding sub elements to it. I just ran the code now and it works. Cheers!